# Почему Laravel для установки пакетов использует NPM?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

День добрый.
Подтягивая теорию, выяснил что:

Node.js - это платформа для выполнения JS как на клиенте, так и на сервере.
Для Node.js существуют модули или пакеты.
NPM - это менеджер, который скачивает, устанавливает, управляет этими пакетами.

Но почему Laravel использует этот же менеджер?
Он что, использует те же пакеты что и Node.js?
Значит ли это, что Laravel сам основан на Node.js?

Очень хочется прояснить картину, чтобы более-менее улеглось в голове.

Comment: На клиенте node.js нет. Насколько я бегло понял, lavarel использует node.js +  npm для сборки фронта.

Comment: Ну да, я имел ввиду, чтобы использовать JS не только на клиенте, но и на сервере. Не понятно что роднит Laravel и Node, почему один и тот же менеджер пакетов может использоваться для обоих? Просто из-за самого факта использования JS?

Answer (score 1):

У laravel по умолчанию есть пресеты (заготовки) для react, vue, boostrap.

NPM там нужен для установки зависимостей этих пресетов и сборки фронта.

Управлять зависимостями js с помощью composer плохая практика. Не зачем делать из инструмента то для чего он не предназначен.

Если вам не нужен js в проекте просто удалите package.json и папку access.

Comment: Я не могу понять другого. Что же роднит Laravel и Node.js? Почему пакеты предназначенные для Node.js подходят на Laravel? Или это не так, и загрузить и установить пакеты для Node.js на Laravel не получиться? Или можно написать любой пакет, под любой фреймворк, а потом просто использовать NPM как загрузчик этого пакета? И тогда ни о какой совместимости речи не идёт?

Comment: Не подходят эти пакеты на lavarel. Это php фрэймворк. Во время его работы нет никакого node.js (если сами не запустите параллельно). Просто есть в наборе инструменты для сборки статики. А статика собирается с помощью node.js. Точно также даже microsoft использует в razor.